# Difference when calculating with average cost.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

Calculating average.
So why am I seeing difference in the value retrieved using below example?

5 Apples at $\$7.00 = 35$

10 Apples at $\$9.00= 90$

14 Apples at $\$5.00 = 70$

So calculating normally I paid $\$195.00$ for $29$ Apples, but if I calculate by average price $\$\frac{7+9+5}3 \times 29=\$203$

Why is there a $\$8$ difference? Thanks!

Comment: You should calculate weighted average

Comment: Being specific, real average price is $\frac{7*5+9*10+5*14}{5+10+14}=6\frac{21}{29}\ne\frac{7+9+5}{3}=7$

Comment: When you "calculate by average price" you are buying $9\frac{2}{3}$ apples at $\$ 7$, $9\frac{2}{3}$ apples at $\$ 9$, and $9\frac{2}{3}$ apples at $\$ 5$,